# Assignment operation on variable in struct not working

Tags: c, variable-assignment

I am writing a c program and have been debugging for a few days now. I think I have figured out the problem.

Here is a snippet of code and the resulting output:

```
// now setting the new RGB values
int blue_val = (long) round(sqrt(((gx_b * gx_b) + (gy_b * gy_b))));
temp[pixel_i][pixel_j].rgbtBlue = blue_val;
printf("%i  %i\n", blue_val, temp[pixel_i][pixel_j].rgbtBlue);
```

Here is the output:

```
322  66
396  140
322  66
262  6
60  60
295  39
322  66
385  129
322  66
```

Note: I also set the green and red values and they are written just fine in the struct. Its only the blue value which I print here that is not written for some reason. For a clearer picture, here is the rest of the code that comes afterwards:

```
temp[pixel_i][pixel_j].rgbtGreen = (long) round(sqrt(((gx_g * gx_g) + (gy_g * gy_g))));
temp[pixel_i][pixel_j].rgbtRed = (long) round(sqrt(((gx_r * gx_r) + (gy_r * gy_r))));

if (temp[pixel_i][pixel_j].rgbtBlue > 255)
    temp[pixel_i][pixel_j].rgbtBlue = 255;
if (temp[pixel_i][pixel_j].rgbtGreen > 255)
    temp[pixel_i][pixel_j].rgbtGreen = 255;
if (temp[pixel_i][pixel_j].rgbtRed > 255)
    temp[pixel_i][pixel_j].rgbtRed = 255;
// printf("R:%i G:%i B:%i\n", temp[pixel_i][pixel_j].rgbtRed, temp[pixel_i][pixel_j].rgbtGreen, temp[pixel_i][pixel_j].rgbtBlue);
return;
```

Comment: What type is `rgbtBlue`? Seems to be something with only 8 bits.

Comment: yes you are correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the variable in the struct rgbtBlue is of type BYTE, so assignments greater than 255 are not allowed.

Solution:

```
// now setting the new RGB values taking care to assign 255 for values greater than 255
int bval = (int) round(sqrt(((gx_b * gx_b) + (gy_b * gy_b))));
temp[pixel_i][pixel_j].rgbtBlue = (bval > 255) ? 255 : bval;
int gval = (int) round(sqrt(((gx_g * gx_g) + (gy_g * gy_g))));
temp[pixel_i][pixel_j].rgbtGreen = (gval > 255) ? 255 : gval;
int rval = (int) round(sqrt(((gx_r * gx_r) + (gy_r * gy_r))));
temp[pixel_i][pixel_j].rgbtRed = (rval > 255) ? 255 : rval;
```

Figured this out seconds after posting..

Comment: It's fine to post a solution to your own question. As it is, this is more of a comment than an answer. Perhaps you could _edit_ your answer and post the final code you came up with [for at least one color (e.g. blue)] to make this more complete.